# How to create list object as public in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, object

I have tried to create public instance for list object. But I cant be able to achieve.

```
    class DimensionDistribution 
    {

      public $Distributionch;
      public $DistributionCount;
    }

class DimensionsValue
     {
        public $DimensionName;

        public function __construct()
         {
            list($Dimensiondistribution)=array(new DimensionDistribution());
         }  

     }




class value extends DimensionsValue
{
    $this->$DimensionName;  // It works fine
    public function __construct()
     {
         $this->$Dimensiondistribution;
         // If I try to call list object in a above method it doesn't show
         // list of variables

     }

}
```

My question is how to create public instance for list object? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: dont you think it should be $this->DimensionName instead of $this->$DimensionName

Comment: Even though it will not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this

```
class DimensionsValue
     {
        public $DimensionName;

        public function __construct()
         {
            list($Dimensiondistribution)=array(new DimensionDistribution());
         }  

     }




class value extends DimensionsValue
{
    $this->$DimensionName;  // It works fine

}

$ DimensionsValue = new  DimensionsValue();
$ DimensionsValue->Dimensiondistribution;
```

Update 1: Try out this, hope it will work

```
class DimensionsValue
{
    public $DimensionName;
    public function newData()
    {

        list($DimensionVar)=array(new DimensionDistribution());
        echo $DimensionVar->Distributionch;
        return $DimensionVar;
    }
}

class verify 
{
function __construct()
    {
         $dm=new DimensionsValue();
         $same=$dm->newData();
         $same->Distributionch;
         $same->DistributionCount;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I undrestend your question but maybe this can help you:

```
class value extends DimensionsValue
{        
    public function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();

     }

}
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer. The overridden constructor does not automatically call its parent constructor. Therfore, one has to manually call `parent::__construct()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this:

```
class DimensionsValue
     {
        public $DimensionName;
        public function __construct()
         {
            list($this->DimensionName)=array(new DimensionDistribution());
         }  
     }
```

And than:

```
class value extends DimensionsValue
{
    $this->$DimensionName;  // It works fine
    public function __construct()
     {             
         $back= $this->DimensionName;
     }
}
```

I am not sure it will work or not, but give a try.